# AttributeError: Unknown property legend in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, seaborn

The seaborn stripplot has a function which allows `hue`.

Using the example from https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.stripplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
ax = sns.stripplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="day", data=tips, jitter=True)
```

[image]

In this case, the legend is quite small, showing a different hue for each day. However, I would like to remove the legend.

Normally, one includes a parameter `legend=False`. However, for `stripplot`, this appears to output an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property legend
```

Can one remove the legend for `stripplots`? If so, how does one do this?

Comment: @EliSadoff I'm a bit slow: how do you entirely remove the legend?

Comment: @EliSadoff Even if the answer is there, a reasonable search on removal topic wouldn't lead you to that question

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `ax.legend_.remove()` like here:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.stripplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="day", data=tips, jitter=True)

# remove legend from axis 'ax'
ax.legend_.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image]