# Hide legend from seaborn pairplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to hide the Seaborn pairplot legend. The official docs don't mention a keyword legend. Everything I tried using `plt.legend` didn't work. Please suggest the best way forward. Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1','2','1','2','2','6','7','7','6','6'],
    'x': [123,22,356,412,54,634,72,812,129,110],
    'y':[120,12,35,41,45,63,17,91,112,151]})
sns.pairplot(x_vars='x', y_vars="y", 
                 data=test,
                 hue = 'id', 
                 height = 3)
```

Comment: You forgot to add 'import pandas as pd' at the beginning to make your code works.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to return the Seabron Pairgrid object when you use `pairplot` and then you can access the legend of the Pairgrid using `._legend`. Then simply call `remove()`:

```
import seaborn as sns

test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1','2','1','2','2','6','7','7','6','6'],
    'x': [123,22,356,412,54,634,72,812,129,110],
    'y':[120,12,35,41,45,63,17,91,112,151]})

g = sns.pairplot(x_vars='x', y_vars="y", data=test, hue = 'id', height = 3)
g._legend.remove()
```

[image]

Comment: Using `._legend` doesn't work for me and throws an `AttributeError`. Using `.legend_` works, however, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38136752/9374673).

Comment: @DavidG. Since I see that for most people Mihai Chelaru's answer works, could you please update your answer changing `_legend` to `legend_`? Thank you!

Comment: No. For me, using a `pairplot` my answer works. The linked answer uses a `stripplot` which returns an `axes` object as opposed to the `PairGrid` object returned by `pairplot`, therefore the answers will not be the same.

Comment: `legend_.remove()` works for me for a seaborn lineplot

Answer (score 62):

Since `_legend.remove()` method won't work on some other seaborn plots, what about:

```
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! 'g._legend.remove()'  did not work on sns.boxplot

Comment: This worked for `scatterplot`

Comment: g =sns.swarmplot(data=...)
    g.legend([],[], frameon=False)

works for me

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove legends on all subplots, you can use the following code.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,5)

# ...

for ax in axes:
    ax.legend([],[], frameon=False)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also just stay on the surface roads, so to speak.

```
ax.get_legend().set_visible(False)
```